# Unambiguous regular expression for binary strings

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

Give decompositions that uniquely create the following sets of 0/1-strings.
All strings with no odd blocks of length greater than 4.

With this problem, I was looking for a regular expression that produces the set of binary strings desired. My attempt:

I know 1*(00* 11* )* 0* is a block decomposition producing all binary strings. I am trying to modify this for the odd block condition. I have done the following:
((11)* U 1 U 111) ((00)* U 0 U 000)((11)* U 1 U 111))* ((00)* U 0 U 000))

My thought process here is to create a block of even 1s and 0s or odd blocks of 0/1s that have length 1 or 3.
I wanted to confirm if I have created a correct regular expression that is unambiguous. Thank you.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Resolved.